# Can buil-in drawing tools be called from within pine-script?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Prior building it from scratch I wonder if I can call built-in drawing tools, e.g. "Date Range" (Drawing Tool to display Volume, Days, ...), from within my custom indicator.

I couldn't find any related intel in the docs and since libraries are available, I wonder if TV ever thought about making the built-ins available / already does and I am just not able to find it.

Appreciate a pointer into the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot call the drawing tools from your script. You can try replicating the tools or look for an open source one. However, most of the drawing tools are not written in `pinescript` so replicating them is not so easy.

Comment: Thanks. Thought so given there was nothing in the docs but simply hoped I missed something. Thanks.